# adding variables inside nested objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to create a nested object that looks like this

```
var a = "example"
{Chatting : {a :{ 'id' :a}}}
```

I can't really find anything online, I tried the code below and its not working

```
myobj['Chatting'][a] = {
'id': a
 }
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What are you trying to do, and how do you know that it's not working?

Comment: Describe what 'not working' is and what you are actually trying to accomplish. In the example you've listed, it's probably down to your indices not being literals.

Comment: Im sorry i have a variable a, and I need to create a nested object using the variable but its just not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the id property of the nested myObj you can try this:

```
var myObj={Chatting : {a :{ 'id' : 'a'}}};
alert(myObj.Chatting.a.id)
```

TO create a nested Object:

```js
var Obj = { };
Obj["nestedObj"] = {};
Obj["nestedObj"]["nestedObj1"] = "value";
console.log(Obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

At once:

```js
var a = "example"
var obj = {Chatting : {a :{ 'id' :a}}};

console.log(obj);
```

Step by step:

```js
var a = "example"
var obj = {};          // create the object obj
obj.Chatting = {};     // create the sub-object Chatting of obj
obj.Chatting.a = {};   // create the sub-object a of Chatting
obj.Chatting.a.id = a; // set it's id to a

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear. 
But i guess, you want get element a, right?

```
let a = {Chatting : {a :{ 'id' : 'a'}}};
console.log(a.Chatting.a);
```

Comment: i edited the question, i need to create the object not access it

Answer (score 0):

attribute names cannot be objects. (string variables are fine)

```js
var a = "example";
var myObj = {
  Chatting: {
    a: { // here it is assumes to be "a"
      "id": a // here exapmle is being stored in to "id"
    }
  }
}

console.log(myObj["Chatting"]["a"])// will let you access it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "example";
var obj = {Chatting : {a :{ 'id' :'a'}}};
```

Please note that in an object {key:value} key is a string not variable. I am defining here id:'a', which will output

```
console.log(obj['Chatting']['a']['id']); // 'a'
```

and adding variable to the object

```
obj['Chatting']['a'] = {'id':a};
```

which will output

```
console.log(obj['Chatting']['a']['id']); // 'example'
```